# how to get selected item from combo box using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Need to retrieve selected item from the `select` element using javascript.

```html
<select id="selected">
  <option value="Default Request" selected disabled>Default Request Service</option>
  <option value="1">Anti-Virus Support and Services</option>
  <option value="2">CSB - Request and Report Forms</option>
  <option value="3">Email Support and Services</option>
  <option value="4">Hardware Support and Services</option>
</select>
<input id="selected_display" type="text" value="" name="subject">
```

Answer (score 0):

solution for you is in next code. You got 2 functions. First is for get value or text of selected item. second is used for set value to input

you have to add listener on on select tag and wait for change of the selected option

Enjoy!

```
function getOption(selector) {
    return {
        val: $(selector + ' option:selected').attr('value'),
      text: $(selector + ' option:selected').text()
    }
  };

function setItem(toSelector, value) {
    jQuery(toSelector).val(value);
}

var output;

jQuery('#selected').on('change', function(){
    output = getOption('#selected');
  setItem('#selected_display', output.val); //change to output.text to show text of selected output
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v4fwxeeu/3/

Comment: I forgot mention that i m using jQuery but you can see it in code :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try it with PHP:

```
<form Name="xxxx" class="xxxx" method="post" Action="xxxx">
    <select id="selected" Name="selected>
        <option value="Default Request" selected disabled>Default Request Service</option>
        <option value="1">Anti-Virus Support and Services</option>
        <option value="2">CSB - Request and Report Forms</option>
        <option value="3">Email Support and Services</option>
        <option value="4">Hardware Support and Services</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

With PHP you can get the value of "selected" with:

```
<?php
   $selected = $_POST['selected'];
   echo $selected;
?>
```

Comment: first reason ... he want to use JS
second: PHP is backend and you need a server ... and if you want to do it dynamicly you need use JS

Comment: *wants :D 

The method in php is wunderful ;) Enjoy!

Comment: yes but still you can not do it in real time without refresh the page if you are not use ajax, but creating a request for this banality is waste of performance